# Android library module does not compile when using classes from pure Kotlin module

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a project using this structure: https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture, and I am trying to convert it to Kotlin.

The domain module compiles just fine, but when I try compile the data module I get the following error:

```
Unresolved reference: ThreadExecutor`
```

and some other similar errors.

These errors are about interfaces, dataclass or Dagger singletons. It seems that the data module cannot find some objects from the domain module (though IntelliJ is not showing any error in the editor).

Here is the ThreadExecutor interface:

```
package com.company.app.domain.executor

import java.util.concurrent.Executor

interface ThreadExecutor : Executor
```

The domain module build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

//noinspection GroovyUnusedAssignment
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
//noinspection GroovyUnusedAssignment
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.6"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.6"
    }
}
```

The global project build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    }
}

clean {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And finally the data module build.gralde:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    publishNonDefault true

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':domain')
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

It looks like the domain jar compiled from Kotlin is not exposing these objects the way the data module expects to, but I currently have no clue as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found why it was not compiling: I had to call "rebuild project" rather than "make project" in order for Android Studio to take all the changes into account.